# Is there a way to go to specific slide on load using angular slick carousel library?

Tags: angular, slick.js

I'm creating an app using angular and needs to implement carousel. I tried using [slick carousel](https://devconquer.com/angular/slick-carousel-in-angular/)

I'm just wondering if I can position the slider on the last slide on first load. Here is the code

```
<ngx-slick-carousel class="carousel" 
  #slickModal="slick-carousel" 
  [config]="slideConfig" 
  (init)="slickInit($event)"
  (breakpoint)="breakpoint($event)"
  (afterChange)="afterChange($event)"
  (beforeChange)="beforeChange($event)">
    <div ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let image of images" class="slide">
      <img src="{{ image.img }}" alt="" width="100%">
    </div>
</ngx-slick-carousel>
    
<div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 45px;">
  <button (click)="addSlide()">Add Slide</button>
  <button (click)="removeSlide()">Remove Slide</button>
  <button (click)="slickModal.slickGoTo(2)">slickGoto 2</button>
  <button (click)="slickModal.unslick()">unslick</button>
</div>
```

How ca I put the `slickModal.slickGoto(2)` in the ts file?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solved this using ViewChild component

```
@ViewChild('slickModal') slickModal: any;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.slickModal.slickGoTo(6);
}
```